# [Android Studio]: Illegal processing instruction target ("xml"); xml (case insensitive) is reserved by the specs

Tags: android, xml-parsing

```
:app:mergeDebugResources 1error

Illegal processing instruction target ("xml"); xml (case insensitive) is reserved by the specs.
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [5,9]
```

what does it says?

please help!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], i.e. at least a tailored version of the xml files in question, so that answerers do not have to guess and can quote in their answers for explaining. Also, creating a MRE sometimes makes you understand your problem and solve the error yourself. See [ask] and [tour].

Answer (score 24):

you have two lines like
`<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8>`
in some .xml file

Answer (score 5):

In my case, there was whitespace at the start of the XML document, before the doctype.